# $SO(2,1)$ invariance of Bures metric

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, density-operator

Suppose that we are given the (infinite dimensional) density matrix with components $(\rho_\lambda)_{mn} = (-1)^{m+n} (1-|\lambda|^2)\lambda^m \bar{\lambda}^n$ where bar means complex conjugate and $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $m =0,1,...$ and $n=0,1,...$. Like in the paper [arXiv:1208.3469](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.3469) I try to prove that the symmetry group of this density matrix is $SO(2,1)$. (Recall: A symmetry of $\rho_\lambda$ is a unitary transformation $U$ (we also require $\det(U)=1$) such that there exists a $\lambda^\prime$ such that $\rho_{\lambda^\prime} = U \rho_\lambda U^\dagger$).

The unitary transformations are given in the paper on page 22 (footnote 10). The rotation in (1,2)-plane is quite trivial to check. But e.g. here they also claim that:

$$U_{km} = \delta_{km} - \frac{\epsilon}{2}(m \delta_{k+1,m} - k \delta_{k,m+1}),$$

corresponds to a symmetry of the density matrix where $\epsilon \ll 1$ (to linear order, this is a boost in the (1,3)-plane). I find this however quite difficult to check. I computed the matrix product:

$$(U \rho_\lambda U^\dagger)_{kl} = U_{km} (\rho_\lambda)_{mn} U_{ln} \approx (\rho_\lambda)_{kl} \Big[1+\frac{\lambda \epsilon}{2}(k+1) - \frac{\epsilon}{2\lambda}k + \frac{\bar{\lambda} \epsilon}{2}(l+1) - \frac{\epsilon}{2\bar{\lambda}}l\Big] \overset{?}{=} (-1)^{k+l}(1-|\lambda^\prime|^2)\lambda^{\prime k}\bar{\lambda}^{\prime l}.$$

How can I find $\lambda^\prime$ from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found a way of doing this. You only have to show that there exists such a $\lambda^\prime$ for the argument to hold. Since the equation holds for arbitrary $k,l$ we can just plug in certain values to find $\lambda^\prime$.

$|\lambda^\prime|$ can be found by $k = l = 0$:

$$(1-|\lambda|^2)\Big(1+\frac{\lambda \epsilon}{2} + \frac{\bar{\lambda} \epsilon}{2}\Big) = (1-|\lambda^\prime|^2).$$

This has the following unique solution for $|\lambda^\prime|$:

$$|\lambda^\prime| = \sqrt{1-(1-|\lambda|^2)(1+\epsilon \mathrm{Re}(\lambda))}.$$

Next by looking at $k=1$, $l=0$ you can actually also find $\lambda^\prime$:
$$(1-|\lambda|^2)\lambda\Big(\lambda \epsilon - \frac{\epsilon}{2\lambda} + \frac{\bar{\lambda}\epsilon}{2}\Big) = (1-|\lambda^\prime|^2) \lambda^\prime.$$

Since we already have a solution for $|\lambda^\prime|$ in terms of $\lambda$ and $|\lambda|$ one can find that there indeed exists a $\lambda^\prime$.